# Mapping over object returns false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'am making a call to a dynamic api to return some values, this call returns a Json like this:

`{name: "test", resource_group: "group1", location: "westeurope", disk_size: "30 GB", os_type: "Linux", …}`

```
let url
const [MachinesRow, setMachinesRow] = React.useState([])
React.useEffect(() => {
resource_group.forEach((keyword, index) => {
 url = "/api/machine/" + keyword + "/" + name[index]
 fetch(url, {
   method: "GET",
   headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     Authorization: "Bearer " + window.localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
   },
 })
.then(resp => {
        return resp.json()
      })
   .then(data => {
     setMachinesRow(data)
   })
   .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
     window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token")
     window.location.replace("/")
    })

 })
}, [])
```

If i do a `{console.log(MachinesRow)}` i get a empty array and 3 Objects, the empty array is because i could not find another solution to get the Objects without getting also undefined values before i got the objects, but when i try to map them like this to get the name for example:

```
const d = MachinesRow.length > 0 && MachinesRow.map((row)=>{
         return (row.name);

     });
```

and then do a `{console.log(d)}` i get:

[image]

This returns false as value and i don't know why, i tried to search but didn't find a similar issue.

Comment: In case `MachinesRow.length == 0`, the `&&` will short-circuit and return `false` for the entire expression initializing `d`. What were you trying to achieve there, again?

Comment: I'am trying to map the Json object. I tried just to make a const that returned a value just to see what was the console.log of it, but what i wanted was to map all the object, but if i don't do ` MachinesRow.length > 0` i will get undefined as a return value before i get my objects and then when i try to map them i will get the error that i can't map over undefined values.

Comment: There are other places to put that check other than the initializer expression, though. Like an if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting your data as many times as many items are in your `resource_group` array, thus you set new data to your state in every iteration. You are setting correct initial data to your state. Then you are trying to put your data together, and it fails. This may help, so:

```
   .then(data => {
     setMachinesRow([...MachinesRow, ...[data]])
   })
```

will collect the data from all your requests. Then you can map `MachinesRow` as array of objects.

Comment: Sorry was my bad, it works now, thanks. There is any way i return just the data without the first array empty because if i do not set `React.useState([])` to an empty array the first response will be undefined